# Replace String with ASCII values between 2 ranges (or)

Tags: java, regex

I would like to replace a string containing unwanted ASCII characters except from these 2 ranges(in `hex`):

`x20-x7e` and `x80-x9a`.

How do I write the correct Regex so that it will replace all characters that are not between `20-7e` and `80-9a`?

I tried this:

```
String fixed = value_.replaceAll("[^(\\x20-\\x7e|\\x80-\\x9a)]", "");
```

But it didn't not work. 
**UPDATE:**
I get a string that has only charecters that are between x20-x7e , all other charecters, including 
x80-x9a are replaced.

how do i use or between those 2 ranges?

Comment: What do you mean by didn't work? What output do you get?

Comment: @Rohit Jain: I've updated with the result I get.

Comment: Since the problem is with the characters >= 0x80, could this be due to an ASCII vs Unicode snafu?

Answer (score 1):

Why not just:

```
String fixed = value_.replaceAll("[^\\x20-\\x7e\\x80-\\x9a]", "");
```

Answer (score 0):

Fix up your regex syntax, and use either use Unicode `\unnnn`

```
String fixed = value_.replaceAll("[^\u0020-\u007e\u0080-\u009a]", "");
```

or octal `\nnn`:

```
String fixed = value_.replaceAll("[^\40-\176\200-\232]", "");
```

FYI While Unicode needs all four digits, octal needs only as many as required.

Comment: I tested the code and it works for me. Please post your input string.